# What do the rankings after the match mean?

Tags: street-fighter-iv, super-street-fighter-iv

After each match you are rated on Offense, Defense and Technique. How exactly do these correlate to events during the match and what effect do they have on the points you get for ranked matches?

Answer (score 1):

Going solely based on what I've seen while playing since I can't seem to find a concrete source for this:

- Offense: based on your successful hit rate and how fast you defeat your opponent
- Defense: based on successful evades/blocks of opponent's attacks and specials
- Technique: based on how well you perform and land combos and specials (for example, a combo what includes a FADC will give you a very high tech grade)

These grades have nothing to do with how many points you gain for a ranked match.  The ranked match increase is purely based on your rank vs your opponent's rank.